# <input> will not update

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

My code uses a hidden iframe to upload then display up to 4 photos on my web page.

The code below adds 1 to the count of current images to keep track of how many have been uploaded.  When I try to store this value into the "thumbImageCount", which is a simple input control on my web page, the input control's **value** is not updating.

The reason for the 'parDoc' in the PHP code below is -- all this PHP code is happening inside my web page's hidden iframe, and I need to update the iframe's parent document, the document object for my web page, not the iframe's document (I'm using the 'hidden iframe' techique in a Ajaxie sort of way):

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">'."\n";
 echo 'var parDoc = parent.document;' . "\n";

 $curImageCount = $curImageCount + 1;
 $outStr = "parDoc.getElementById('justOpenedImage').innerHTML = '<div><img id=\'editImage\' class=\'normSizeImg\' src=\'$fullImagePath\' /></div>';";
 $outStr3 = "\n parDoc.getElementById('picture_path_hidden').value = '" . $fullImagePath . "';";
 $outStr4 = "\n parDoc.getElementById('" . $thumbWindowName . "').src = '" . $fullImagePath . "';";
 $outStr5 = "\n parDoc.getElementById('" . $thumbWindowName . "').style.display = 'inline-block';";
 $outStr6 = "\n parDoc.getElementById('thumbImageCount').value = '" . $curImageCount . "';";
 $outStr7 = "\n alert('photoPreview.php, the new image count (aka curImageCount) is: " . $curImageCount . "');";
 echo $outStr;  
 echo $outStr3;  
 echo $outStr4;  
 echo $outStr5;  
 echo $outStr6;  
 echo $outStr7;  
 echo "\n".'</script>';
```

Notice in **outStr7** the iframe puts up an 'alert' box on the parent (my web page's) document.  THAT ALERT tells me the image count has successfully incremented.

Notice that in **outStr6** I save that same image count into an input element with the id of 'thumbImageCount'.

So in my mind, since the alert box in outStr7, which comes *after* outStr6, is showing the correct newly-increment image count, so should the 'thumbImageCount' input control on my page.

IT DOESN'T.    Here is the html for the 'thumbImageCount' on my web page:

```
 <input id="thumbImageCount" name="thumbImageCount" type="hidden" 
                                 value="<?php echo $imageCount ?>" />
```

My web page allows uploading and displaying 4 images.  And to do this, the page is *not* re-posted to the web server (I avoid that by using the hidden iframe technique).

So while you notice above that I set the initial value in the html tag for my **thumbImageCount** input control to a PHP variable called 'imageCount', which is 0 (zero) -- since my web page only loads one time, that input contro's **value**, after being initialized by the PHP variable to zero (0), should be able to be updated by this line of my hidden iframe's PHP code from above:

```
 $outStr6 = "\n parDoc.getElementById('thumbImageCount').value = '" . $curImageCount . "';";
```

But it's not happening.   After loading 4 images, I do a 'view page source' on my web page to see if that 'thumbImageCount' input control has been updated to a value of 4, and this is what I see:

```
 <input id="thumbImageCount" name="thumbImageCount" type="hidden" 
                                 value="0" />
```

So if you look at all the 'outStrs' in my PHP code above, *all those are working* -- the images appear fine on my web page.  Only outStr6 fails.

What am I missing here?   The reason I need the 'thumbImageCount' to update correctly on my web page is I need to set the 'selected image' to the newly-uploaded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not found here; I had to repost and reframe this question, which I did at:  [document updating but getElementById() returns incorrect value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203017/document-updating-but-getelementbyid-returns-incorrect-value/19204271#19204271)

Ultimately the problem was being caused by the page, the DOM, being buffered and the solution was to force the DOM to update so that getElementById() would retrieve the updated state of the  **thumbImageCount** input element.  Apparently when something on the page is modified, the DOM does not update immediately, and I had to force it to update, which is described in a new post at the above link.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing fundamentally incorrect about your code. If your input weren't hidden, you would have seen that its value has been changed.

[image: g]

However, you will not see the code changing via "view page source", because the source code does not change dynamically - its "copy" in memory, known as the DOM, does.

Please, in the future, use the browser's developer tools to inspect dynamic changes, and for all our sake, please don't do "ajax" using iframes.

Comment: thanks, curious about what pitfalls you think of when using the hidden iframe technique to dynamically update the page? It works fine.

Comment: after checking the value, it does increment.  But it increments *after* the alert box above displays.  Any idea why? That is what's breaking the code, the increment happens late.

Comment: Domain origin restrictions, inability to make any request other than GET, the general WTF factor... surely many things 'work', but that's like hitting a nail with a can opener.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add to @Brian's answer, with a suggestion regarding your code output. It is not necessary, or a good idea, to output code as you are. I would suggest using multiple lines as below:

```
echo <<<END
<script type="text/javascript">
     var parDoc = parent.document;
     parDoc.getElementById('justOpenedImage').innerHTML = '<div><img id=\'editImage\' class=\'normSizeImg\' src=\'$fullImagePath\' /></div>';
     parDoc.getElementById('picture_path_hidden').value = '$fullImagePath';
     parDoc.getElementById('$thumbWindowName').src = '$fullImagePath';
     parDoc.getElementById('$thumbWindowName').style.display = 'inline-block';
     parDoc.getElementById('thumbImageCount').value = '$curImageCount';
     alert('photoPreview.php, the new image count (aka curImageCount) is: $curImageCount');
</script>
END;
```

This looks a lot cleaner, and is easier to read. Remember to escape any `$` if they are not variables, though that does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've got HEREDOCS as you show above all over my code. However, I'm pretty new to this stuff and I like to expose myself to different ways of doing things.

Comment: Also just noticed now, but you can use `$curImageCount++` to increment a variable by one.